# How can I return a component by its type in a Mixin class?

Tags: c++, c++11, mixins, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I've been experimenting with using variadic templates to implement a GameObject class using Mixins (combined with CRTP for static polymorphism). I have everything working, but `GameObject`'s `getComponent()` method requires both the type and the index, which is cumbersome. Can `getComponent()` be rewritten so that it only needs the type OR the index of the component I want?

Here is the code for the components that make up the Mixins:

```
class ComponentBase {
public:
    virtual void update () = 0;
};

template <class T>
class Component : public ComponentBase {
public:
    virtual void update () {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->update();
    }
};

class TransformComponent : public Component<TransformComponent> {
public:
    void update () {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
protected:
    int _x, _y;
};

class ColliderComponent : public Component<ColliderComponent> {
public:
    void update () {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
protected:
    bool _collided;
};
```

And then here is the `GameObject` Mixin class:

```
template <class ... Mixins>
class GameObject : private Mixins...
{
public:
    GameObject (const Mixins&... mixins) : Mixins(mixins)..., _components{&mixins...} {}
    GameObject (Mixins&&... mixins) : Mixins(std::forward<Mixins>(mixins))..., _components{&mixins...} {}

    constexpr size_t getNumComponents () const { return _numComponents; };

    template <typename T, int index>
    constexpr T* getComponent () const {
        static_assert(index < _numComponents, "getComponent: index out of range");
        return static_cast<T*>(_components[index]);
    }

    void update () {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < getNumComponents(); ++i) {
            _components[i]->update();
        }
    }

protected:
    static const size_t _numComponents = sizeof...(Mixins);
    ComponentBase* _components[sizeof...(Mixins)];
};
```

I thought of using auto return value as in:

```
template <int index>
constexpr auto getComponent() const -> decltype(_components[index]) {
    return _components[index];
}
```

but `decltype` can't evaluate the expression in a method declaration.

I also tried using template recursion for `getComponent()` taking in the type of the component, but you can't specialize a class method within an unspecialized templated class. 
i.e.:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr T* getComponent () const {
    // If T equals the type of _components[index], then return, else
    // call getComponent<T, index - 1>().
}
```

I'm fairly new to working with TMP, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: "...but decltype can't evaluate the expression in a method declaration." You can place `components` above the function so it can access it.

Comment: Why are you capturing pointers to the constructor argument objects to `update` instead of calling `update` on the mixin base objects? Are you guaranteeing that the objects referenced in the constructor call outlive the `GameObject`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Ah yes, thanks. That completely slipped my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, i think something is going wrong here:

```
 GameObject (const Mixins&... mixins) : Mixins(mixins)..., _components{&mixins...} {}
 GameObject (Mixins&&... mixins) : Mixins(std::forward<Mixins>(mixins))..., _components{&mixins...} {}
```

It looks like you want to store the given objects within your mixin object as private base classes, but you are taking pointers to the original objects for your `_components` member. If the original objects are moved, you are even taking pointers to object that are most likely moved out.

Because of this, it's not 100% clear to me what you really want, but here is a solution based on `std::tuple` instead of multiple private inheritance:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/178be711a9a62f2b

As you can see, we don't need a common base class. All types that offer a `update` method are supported by the mixin. Of course you can modifiy it to require the base class, if you need it elsewhere.

Comment: Good point about the original objects. The tuple solution looks better, thanks!

Comment: Oh, and the reason I went with private inheritance at first is because it is similar to the Component's "has-a" relationship.

Answer (score 2):

The `GetComponent<T>()` method that needs only a type, and returns a pointer to an appropriate component (based on little simplified code):

[Live demo link.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/631acb9b5d3a5da7)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, int N, typename... Mixins> 
struct get_index
{
    static constexpr int value = -1;
};

template <typename T, int N, typename... Mixins>
struct get_index<T, N, T, Mixins...>
{
    static constexpr int value = N;
};

template <typename T, int N, typename U, typename... Mixins>
struct get_index<T, N, U, Mixins...>
{
    static constexpr int value = get_index<T, N + 1, Mixins...>::value;
};

class ComponentBase {
public:
    virtual void update () = 0;
};

template <class T>
class Component : public ComponentBase {
public:
    virtual void update () {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->update();
    }
};

class TransformComponent : public Component<TransformComponent> {
public:
    void update () {
        std::cout << "TransformComponent" << std::endl;
    }
protected:
    int _x, _y;
};

class ColliderComponent : public Component<ColliderComponent> {
public:
    void update () {
        std::cout << "ColliderComponent" << std::endl;
    }    
protected:
    bool _collided;
};

template <typename... Mixins>
class GameObject
{
public:
    GameObject(Mixins&... mixins) : _components{&mixins...} {}
    GameObject(Mixins&&... mixins) : _components{&mixins...} {}

    constexpr size_t getNumComponents () const { return _numComponents; };

    template <typename T>
    constexpr int getIndex() const {
        return get_index<T, 0, Mixins...>::value;
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr T* getComponent() const {
        if (getIndex<T>() != -1)
            return static_cast<T*>(_components[getIndex<T>()]);
        else
            return nullptr;
    }

    void update () {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < getNumComponents(); ++i) {
            _components[i]->update();
        }
    }

protected:
    static const size_t _numComponents = sizeof...(Mixins);
    ComponentBase* _components[sizeof...(Mixins)];
};

int main()
{
    ColliderComponent c{};
    TransformComponent t{};

    GameObject<ColliderComponent, TransformComponent> b{ c, t };

    b.getComponent<ColliderComponent>()->update();
    b.getComponent<TransformComponent>()->update();
}
```